# missing ] after element list (JSON.parse using reviver )

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script

Executing that:

```
function myFunction() {
  var hash = JSON.parse('{"a":"return num"}', function(k, v){ new Function('num', v)(123) });
}
```

I want to get hashmap:
    {a=123}

However, Google Apps Script Says:

> SyntaxError: missing ] after element list

I know below code works well, but I want that the value of JSON contains "return".

```
function myFunction() {
  var num = 123;
  var hash = JSON.parse('{"a": "num"}', function(k, v){return eval(v)});
}
```

Comment: `'{"a":"' + num + '"}'`

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Actually, JSON is fetched from Gmail Drafts, so your code doesn't work. I apologize for any confusion to simplify code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reviver function runs once for every item found in the input. In the case of this JSON string:

```
{"a":"return num"}
```

it will run two times (!). First for the inner key-value pair `"a":"return num"` and then for the root object itself (key-value pair `"": {"a":"return num"}`).

You only want to do something when the key is `"a"`, in all other cases you want to return the value unchanged.

```js
var json = '{"a":"return num"}';
var revived = JSON.parse(json, function (k, v) {
    if (k === "a") {
        return (new Function('num', v))(123);
    } else {
        return v;
    }
});

console.log(revived);
```

Be careful, doing this is dangerous. `new Function` is effectively the same as `eval()`, so I suggest you think hard about better ways of doing what you want.

How about using a config object and a special syntax convention to replace certain values in the data with values from the config:

```js
var config = {
    num: 123
};

var json = '{"a":"{{num}}"}';
var revived = JSON.parse(json, function (k, v) {
    var match = typeof v === "string" && v.match(/^{{(\w+)}}$/);
    if (match && config.hasOwnProperty(match[1])) {
        return config[match[1]];
    } else {
        return v;
    }
});

console.log(revived);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your advice, your code works well. I understand a risk of my code. I will consider other ways.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Give my second suggestion some thought, avoid `new Function()` if you can.

Comment: Thanks. Your second suggestion give me new knowledge. Your second code is not possible for my current program because my program do 
string operation by codes given by values of JSON, but I consider new way based on your suggestions.